# Lambda expression to loop through two concurrent dictionaries

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, concurrency, lambda

I am trying to loop through two concurrent dictionaries like the code below, however I want to use a lambda expression instead

```
foreach (var s in sb_eventdata)
{  
    foreach (var f in final_data)
    {
        if (s.Value.Car.Equals(f.Value.Car))
        {
            Console.Writeline("Found!");
        }
    }
}
```

`var values = sb_eventdata.Where(k => k.Value.Hometeam.Contains( ???? );`

I'm really not sure what to pass into contains, I assume another lambda expression but what?

Comment: Your example code is answering the question "Does anything in list A match a record in List B?" (if so, write "Found").
That's a different question from "Give me the records in List A that match records in List B" which the `var values =` implies.

Comment: To simplify/clarify my comment: do you want the resulting list of common objects (and assign them to a `values` collection), or do you want to do something if matches exist (like `Console.Writeline`)? If you want the resulting list, use `Intersect`, to detect there are results, use `Any`.

Comment: Finally, if you want to create a side-effect (like a printing of "Found" on each match) use `ForEach` (Assuming they are `List`s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest linq expression to your loops would be:

```
var sb_eventdata = new Dictionary<string, string>{ {"a", "a"}, {"b", "b"}};
var final_data = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"a", "a"}, {"b", "b"}, {"c","c"}};

var result = 
    // first loop
    sb_eventdata.Select(s => 
        // second loop
        final_data.Where(f => s.Value.Equals(f.Value)))
    // flatten results (returns results from the first dictionary)
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Thank you! This returned the final_data object, which i was able to process further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [linq `Intersect` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to find like items in a list.
Then display all like items.

```
    var foo = sb_eventdata.Select(o => o.Value.Car).Intersect(final_data.Select(o => o.Value.Car));
    foreach (var item in foo)
    {

        Console.Writeline("Found!");

    }
```

Comment: As long as the collection type implements `IEquatable<T>`, yes. Since the example code uses `Equals` I think you're on solid ground with that assumption. If the type isn't equatable, you'd use `Join` as @AnonymousTroll suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

I think your friend is the Join() method.

In "LinqPad style":

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new[] {
        new Car("Opel",200),
        new Car("Volkswagen",300),
        new Car("Audi", 500)
    };

    var b = new[] {
        new Car("Peugeot", 180),
        new Car("Seat", 300),
        new Car("Volvo", 480)
    };

    var c = a.Join(b, ak => ak.Value, bk => bk.Value, (ak,bk) => new {A=ak.Name,B=bk.Name,ak.Value});
    c.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

class Car {
    public string Name;
    public int Value;

    public Car (string name, int value) {
      Name = name;
      Value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if both dictionary share at least one value, you can use Any:

```
if(sb_eventdata.Any(s => 
    final_data.Any(f => s.Value.Car.Equals(f.Value.Car))))
         Console.WriteLine("Found!");
```

or with Contains:

```
if(sb_eventdata.Any(s => final_data.ContainsValue(s.Value)))
         Console.WriteLine("Found!");
```

and if you want to count how many of sb_eventdata are in final_data:

```
sb_eventdata.Where(s => final_data.ContainsValue(s.Value)).Count();
```